# need a reference/text book for 'Ruby on Rails 4'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to purchase book for Ruby on Rails 4.
can anyone suggest reference/text book for 'Ruby on Rails 4'. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: there is a website called www.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider buying the Ruby on Rails tutorial book by Michael Hartl. Its really great if you are new to Ruby on Rails: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

If you can wait until summer you should definitely have a look at "The Rails 4 Way": http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Rails-Addison-Wesley-Professional-Ruby/dp/0321944275/ref=sr_1_6?ie=UTF8&qid=1397115031&sr=8-6&keywords=ruby+on+rails+4